# Why is not possible to use range() like this?

Tags: php

Why is not possible to assign a variable with `range()` here?

```
class foo
{
    //
    // Error
    public static $bar = range(1, 10);

    //
    // Error
    public $bar = range(1, 10);

    //
    // Works
    public static $zoo = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot initialize class properties with the result of a function call.

`array()` is a language construct and not a function so it does work.

Comment: What drives me mad is that you can't even set properties to the value of another property or even use concatenation.

Comment: Switch to python and you *can* do all those nice things. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't set initial [class properties using functions or variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php), just like you can't set [default function argument values with functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize it in the constructor:

```
class foo
{
    // Works
    public $bar;
    
    function __construct() {
        $bar = range(1, 10);
    }
}
```